# Search And Scrape data from a website using R

Tags: r

I have 1000 records with emailaddress and all other address information. For which I want information for each record from this website [https://www.melissadata.com/lookups/businesscoder.asp][1]. Is there any way to automate this process.

Comment: You should start with rvest package and selectorGadget.

Comment: @RicardoFernandesCampos..Any example or tutorial on how to do it?

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-rvest-to-scrape-an-html-table/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working three liner example on how to extract every link from a website:

```
# r library for making requests
library(httr)
# r library for parsing XML and HTML
library(XML)

# performing GET request to website
response <- GET("https://www.melissadata.com/lookups/index.htm", encoding="UTF-8")
# parse response as html in order to run xpath queries
parsedoc <- htmlParse(response)
# perform xpath search query on parsed document
links <- xpathSApply(parsedoc, "//a", xmlGetAttr, "href")
```

To web scrape you should get known with xpath queries: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

Comment: @Kozielski-Romaneczko..How I will read my csv in this query? Just using read.csv in R or something diffferent?

Comment: Hmm I fought that your intend is to know how to scrape data from website. My code gives you example by which you can get every link on a website. Now there is some csv file which you want to read in... Please clarify what are you aiming at with this code, because I don't know how can I help. What data you are trying to scrape, what data you have in your csv., and what you want to perform with it.